# how to create an ExternalLink on a page that refers to the previous page

Tags: java, html, http, web-applications, wicket

I'm implementing an error page for my application, and would like to know how to implement a wicket ExternalLink to the previous page? 
I think I have to save the parameters, or the whole URL of the previous page, but I'm not sure and I don't know how to do that.. do you have any idea?

I'm using Wicket / WicketPages..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Link` that has a `setReponsePage(YourClass.class, pageParameters)` in the `onClick`. However, you lose the state that the previous page had.

Alternatively, you could try a javascript:`history.go(-1)`. This would try to go back to the previous page within the browser.

It totally depends on what you define as 'the last page'